# How to count rows from MySQL with PDP PDO Prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code to count number of rows in PHP PDO

```
$sql = "SELECT count(name) FROM `info` WHERE name='$name' "; 
$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$totalrows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

But the problem is, If the `$name` contain an `'`, it gives error. Prepared statement is fast, secure and better. How to convert it into prepared statement?

I tried to make it PHP PDO statement, but it is not working

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(name) FROM `info` WHERE name='$name' "); 
$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));
$totalrows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This is not how you use prepared statements. `SELECT count(name) FROM info WHERE name=?` then `$result->execute(array($name));`

Comment: You only did 1/4 of what i said. You chose to use a named array, but didnt use a named placeholder, or a placeholder at all.

Comment: I really do not understand, what you mean. I am not expert :/. This is what you said, where is the 3/4th part? Sorry

Comment: I changed the query and the `execute`, you ignored the query change and only changed the `execute` (and changed it to named version).

Comment: As your previous post, this is not how prepared statements work. Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php